# RxJava2 - Reuse operator sequence for multiple Rx chains

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following Rx chain:

```
compositeDisposable.add(manager.getObservable()
            .map(objects -> modelMapper.map(objects))
            .map(modelObjects -> {
                cache.save(modelObjects);
                return modelObjects ;
            })
            .flatMapIterable(modelObjects -> modelObjects)
            .sorted(objectComparator)
            .toList()
            .map(modelObjects -> viewModelMapper.map(modelObjects))
            .subscribe(this::onObjectsLoaded));
```

I want to extract the operators `flatMapIterable(modelObjects -> modelObjects)`, `sorted(objectComparator)` and `toList()` into a separate method that I can reuse in multiple Rx chains to sort the objects, so the chain will look something like this:

```
compositeDisposable.add(manager.getObservable()
            .map(objects -> modelMapper.map(objects))
            .map(modelObjects -> {
                cache.save(modelObjects );
                return modelObjects ;
            })
            .compose(sortObjects())
            .map(modelObjects -> viewModelMapper.map(modelObjects))
            .subscribe(this::onObjectsLoaded));
```

Is is possible to create such a method?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it? Also there is a `toSortedList` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a method that takes an `Observable` and returns an `Observable`:

```java
static <T> Observable<List<T>> sortListItem(Observable<List<T>> source,
        Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    return source.flatMapIterable(v -> v)
                .toSortedList(comparator)
                .toObservable();
}

compositeDisposable.add(manager.getObservable()
        .map(objects -> modelMapper.map(objects))
        .map(modelObjects -> {
            cache.save(modelObjects);
            return modelObjects ;
        })
        .compose(ThisClass::sortListItem)
        .map(modelObjects -> viewModelMapper.map(modelObjects))
        .subscribe(this::onObjectsLoaded));
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a static method instead of explicitly defining an `ObservableTransformer` class? (I understand that's what you're implicitly doing with the method reference.)

Comment: You need to host the code in some way and make it available to multiple use places. It is up to you which structure you choose.

Comment: @akarnokd This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Marked as accepted.